# Recordset adds new record into sub form but on save nothing added to table

Tags: ms-access, vba

Hi I am adding new record into subform via recordsetclone method. The problem is that new record appears in the form but on save it does not appear in the table. If add this record manually everything works. If record added manually update section of if statement works fine.

here is my code.

```
'Add Wastage value to flooring area section
Private Sub Wastage_AfterUpdate()
    Dim rsFlArea As DAO.Recordset
    Dim Wastage As Double
    Dim Item As String
    Set rsFlArea = Me.OrderFloorAreaEdit.Form.RecordsetClone
    'Caluate Wastage amount based on the percentage in parent form
    Wastage = Format((Me.FloorMeterage.Value * Me.Wastage.Value), "#,##0.00")

    'Check if it has been already added if not than add - note 12 is ID of floor area
    rsFlArea.FindFirst "[Item] LIKE '12'"
    If rsFlArea.NoMatch Then
            rsFlArea.AddNew
            rsFlArea!Item = 12
            rsFlArea!Units = Wastage
            rsFlArea!uPrice = Me.flPrice.Value
            rsFlArea.Update
        Else
        ' If value exist in recordset than update the value
        Do Until rsFlArea.EOF
            If rsFlArea!Item = 12 Then
                rsFlArea.Edit
                rsFlArea!Units = Format(((Me.FloorMeterage.Value - Nz(rsFlArea!Units, 0)) * Me.Wastage.Value), "#,##0.00")
                rsFlArea.Update
            End If
            rsFlArea.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If

    rsFlArea.Close
    Set rsFlArea = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to issue either a 'Refresh' or a 'Requery' of your subform?  Is the record added to the underlying table?

Comment: If I DoCmd.Requery it simply does not appear in the subform. Its as if AddNew doesn't work, but edit update works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I have linked the subform query to OrderID and forgot to add it so additional field fixed it. So it was adding new field but without OrderID thats why it did not show up in the subform as it was filtered out.

```
'Add Wastage value to flooring area section
Private Sub Wastage_AfterUpdate()
    Dim rsFlArea As DAO.Recordset
    Dim Wastage As Double
    Dim Item As String
    Set rsFlArea = Me.OrderFloorAreaEdit.Form.RecordsetClone
    'Caluate Wastage amount based on the percentage in parent form
    Wastage = Format((Me.FloorMeterage.Value * Me.Wastage.Value), "#,##0.00")

    'Check if it has been already added if not than add - note 12 is ID of floor area
    rsFlArea.FindFirst "[Item] LIKE '12'"
    If rsFlArea.NoMatch Then
            rsFlArea.AddNew
            rsFlArea!OrderID = Me.OrderID.Value
            rsFlArea!Item = 12
            rsFlArea!Units = Wastage
            rsFlArea!uPrice = Me.flPrice.Value
            rsFlArea.Update
        Else
        ' If value exist in recordset than update the value
        Do Until rsFlArea.EOF
            If rsFlArea!Item = 12 Then
                rsFlArea.Edit
                rsFlArea!Units = Format(((Me.FloorMeterage.Value - Nz(rsFlArea!Units, 0)) * Me.Wastage.Value), "#,##0.00")
                rsFlArea.Update
            End If
            rsFlArea.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If

    rsFlArea.Close
    Set rsFlArea = Nothing
End Sub
```